# Python Manager access dict through registry

Tags: python, dictionary, proxy, multiprocessing

I have a manager with one dict proxy. I want to access it from a different process. For brevity sample code only uses one process but assume we don't have a direct reference to it (as if the other process was created from the first one).
I register dict proxy dict1 under typeName 'd1' so I can access it remotely. I check the manager's registry and see the dict proxy there.
But when I try to access it by calling d1 I get a KeyError from the remote. I know I could create a method to access my dict, but there must be a direct way to access the dict proxy according to the documentation (python 2, chapter 16.6).

```
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager
from sys import stderr

proxy = SyncManager()
proxy.start()

dict1 = proxy.dict({'k1': 'blah'})
proxy.register('d1', dict1)

# next line shows that d1 is bound method of manager
print >>stderr, 'd1 is', proxy.d1

# next line produces a KeyError
print 'The value of d1 is', proxy.d1()
```

Run output

```
d1 is <bound method SyncManager.d1 of <multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager object at 0x10925dd10>>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adriancepleanu/PycharmProjects/AFX/UIproxy.py", line 32, in <module>
    print 'The value of d1 is', proxy.d1()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 667, in temp
    token, exp = self._create(typeid, *args, **kwds)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 567, in _create
    id, exposed = dispatch(conn, None, 'create', (typeid,)+args, kwds)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 105, in dispatch
    raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
multiprocessing.managers.RemoteError: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 207, in handle_request
    result = func(c, *args, **kwds)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 380, in create
    self.registry[typeid]
KeyError: 'd1'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Found that the proxy server must be started *after* the call to register the new type; it appears that registrations made after the proxy was started will not function.